# How to reference a list within a function?

Tags: python

I am trying to use the for loop to do that: when the `stack number = 'Stack 1'`, when the suit type is 'Suit A', it will run the `card_red` function the number of times specified in the third item in the first list (9)

```
game1 = \
[['Stack 1', 'Suit A', 9, 6],
['Stack 2', 'Suit B', 5, 0]]


def deal_cards():
    if     == 'Stack 1':
        if      == 'Suit A':
            for i in range(     ):
                card_red(stack1_xpos, stack1_ypos)
```

So what do I put after each "if" statement and in the range() brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to loop over a list of items, while also getting the position of the item:

```
game1 = \
[['Stack 1', 'Suit A', 9, 6],
['Stack 2', 'Suit B', 5, 0]]


def deal_cards():
  for (idx, stack) in enumerate(game1):
    if stack[0] == 'Stack 1':
        if stack[1] == 'Suit A':
            for i in range(stack(2)):
                card_red(idx, 3)
```

So Your loop will run twice,

- first with `idx = 0` and `stack = ['Stack 1', 'Suit A', 9, 6]`,
- then with `idx = 1` and `['Stack 2', 'Suit B', 5, 0]`

Answer (score 2):

It appears you have a list of lists. Use index notation with square brackets to access individual elements of a list.

```
def deal_cards():
    if game1[0][0] == 'Stack 1':
        if game1[0][1] == 'Suit A':
            for i in range(game1[0][2]):
                card_red(stack1_xpos, stack1_ypos)
```

Notice here that in each case, first I use index `[0]` to access the first sub-list, then a second index to access the individual element. Remember that the first item has an index of 0, the second is index 1, etc.

If you want to repeat this for each sub list, it is easier to pass it in as an argument to `deal_cards`:

```
def deal_cards(game):
    if game[0] == 'Stack 1':
        if game[1]== 'Suit A':
            for i in range(game[2]):
                card_red(stack1_xpos, stack1_ypos)


for game in game1:
    deal_cards(game)
```

And notice now that there are only single index accesses in the function whereas before there were double index accesses. This is because the `game` variable already will hold a sublist when called.

Comment: Thanks this works, however what if I want to check if the first item from both the first and second sublist are 'Stack 1'?

Comment: Ah, you’d have to add an extra loop somewhere. In my example, I changed the code so that `deal_cards` handles a single sub list at a time.

Comment: Have a look at my code above - the last 2 lines `for game in game1...` iterate over each sublist and pass it to `deal_cards`

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
game1 = [['Stack 1', 'Suit A', 9, 6],['Stack 2', 'Suit B', 5, 0]]

def deal_cards():
    if game1[0][0] == "Stack1":
        if game1[0][1] == "Suit A":
            for i in range(game1[0][2]):
                card_red(stack1_xpos, stack1_ypos)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try below:

```
game1 = \
[['Stack 1', 'Suit A', 9, 6],
['Stack 2', 'Suit B', 5, 0]]


def deal_cards(arr):
    if arr[0] == 'Stack 1':
        if arr[1] == 'Suit A':
            for i in range(arr[2]):
                card_red(stack1_xpos, stack1_ypos)

for game in game1:
    deal_cards(game) # you can call in this way
```